# Keep two Hg branches in sync

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have two branches in Mercurial. One is for debugging on my local computer, because there are some wampserver settings that are only valid on local machines.

The other branch is for publishing and thus contains the server settings that are required on the web server itself. Unfortunately, even a simple `index.php` is different, because of the `<base>` tag.

I was wondering how to keep these two branches in sync, without having to merge my local changes to the publish branch every time I want to publish.

Is there a better way to maintain these two branches? Can I for example, commit changes to two branches at the same time?

[image: I merge my files every time I have changes to the other branch.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest to see at and at least try [MQ Extension](https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension)

In MQ-powered workflow you'll get single branch + single patch in MQ queue:

- Branch (permanent changesets) represents your mainline-development with DEV configuration
- Patch holds changes, needed for converting DEV into PROD
- You qpop|qpush patch in order to switch between two configuration, change codebase **always** with unapplied path in DEV environment, push (and resolve possible conflicts|refresh patch) patch in order to get changed code for PROD environment

**Note**

Except graft, MQ-less workflow also can be based on [rebase](https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension) (with `--keep` option)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [graft](https://selenic.com/hg/help/graft) instead of merge.

Well, that is quite similar with `merge` in terms of history tree... But for your purposes it could be a little cleaner.